# Easy way to change Firemonkey button pressed color on Android

Tags: android, delphi, button, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

This might be one of those forehead-slapping questions, but what I want to do, is make my buttons show orange (xFFFCB447) when they are pressed, just like the Android dialogs do. (picklist for example)

There doesn't seem to be a specific "pressed" TRectangle in the Default Style, and my adding different TRectangles (coloured appropriately doesn't seem to do it either), so my only alternative seems to be to use the Bitmap Style designer to Export the style.png; hope I figure out which part of the image is used for the button pressed before tomorrow afternoon, and Update the image again.

Is there not an easier/quicker way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option A) Drop a TRectangle on your button. Set it's Align to Contents. Set it's fill color to Orange. Set it's Opacity to 0.50. Set it's HitTest to False. Set it's Visible to False. In the TButton.OnMouseDown set the TRectangle Visible to True. In the TButton.OnMouseUp set the TRectangle Visible to False. You will also need to set the OnMouseMove of the control that TButton is on to set TRectangle Visible to False as well so if you mouse down and then move away it will be hidden as well.

Option B) Drop a TFillRGBEffect on the TButton. Set it to Orange. Do the same as above to enable and disable the effect on mouse down and up. However, be aware that TFillRGBEffect may be slower than the TRectangle way.

Option C) Just use a TRectangle instead of a TButton. Put a TText or TLabel inside it for the text and align to Contents. Change it's Fill color in OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Ok, so why does a rectangle appear semi-transparent (shows underlying panel label) even thought the color starts with $FF and Opacity is set to 1?

Comment: Did you change the opacity of the TRectangle's parent?

Comment: No. Everything is Opacity=1, and yet it is semi-transparent. Is there a global setting in the .style file that makes this happen?

Comment: TRectangles are not styled that I know of. A TRectangle is not semi transparent in any of my apps unless I set the properties to make it so.

Comment: My mistake. I had set the TintColor on a button - and of course, tint is semi-transparent, not opaque.

Comment: One sane piece of doc on FMX style in the whole world. Don't know who is writing the EMB's posts on Styling FMX. Its a nightmare.